# How do I pre-fill a lead's information such as name and email on a linked page using HTML?

Tags: html, email, email-attachments

I know you have to use {{firstname}} so the lead's name shows up in an initial email they receive, but how do you transfer that data to a linked page?

For example, I'm sending email ads for a client, but when the lead clicks on the client's link in the email, they are sent to the client's site and the pre-filled names and email are the same for everyone who clicks on the link.

How do I get that {{firstname}} information to show up in the form on the client's site?

Comment: What software are you using? Seems like a critical point.

Comment: Html is not a dynamic language, you need to use something that generates the html code for you. Are you using some kind of software?

Comment: It depends what email system you are using? for example Dotmailer. You also need to have a database link with all your clients firstnames

Comment: I'm using notepad++.  I'm an intern and not really familiar with this stuff...

Comment: Basically I only have control over the initial email sendout.  The client won't let me edit the source code on their linked site, so would they have to send me something or is the problem on my end do you think?